# Kotlin - Setter for Properties Initialized in Constructor?

Tags: kotlin

hope I worded this right. Trying to be able to do a setter function for a variable that is initialized in a constructor ala:

```
package com.example.propory

class Property(val name: String, propValue: String) {

    var previousPropertyValue: List<String> = listOf("testing")

    var propValue: String = ""
        set(value){
            previousPropertyValue += this.propValue
            field = value
        }
}
```

I can access "name" just fine outside of this when I create a instance of it ala:

```
// trunicated
 val currentProperty = Properties.find { prop -> property.name == prop.name}
```

however if I try to access "propValue":

```
currentProperty.propValue = property.propValue
```

I don't get any value :(.

So wondering what I did wrong and how to fix it. Thank you all for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're leaving the `propValue` parameter that is passed into the constructor completely unused, and initializing your property with an empty String. Initialize it with the parameter that was passed into the constructor:

```
var propValue: String = propValue
    set(value){
        previousPropertyValue += this.propValue
        field = value
    }
```

Comment: ....can't believe I didn't think of that lmao. Thank you so much.